# Why is there a [ ] in input([prompt])?

Tags: python, string, input, newline, prompt

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

See the above link. **Now, the below questions may be silly, but wanted to make myself clear**.

**First Question**:
Why is there a `[]` in `input([prompt])`? Does it signify anything?

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

**Second Question**: Why does it need to convert the input to a *string*? Isn't the input from the `sys.stdin` already a *string*?

**Third Question**: What does *stripping a trailing newline* means in this case?

Comment: It means it's optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[]` in the python docs indicates optional arguments - not, confusingly, the need for a list as an argument.

The input from a modern UTF-8 terminal may well be bytes, so conversion to a string is done to avoid confusion.

`stripping a trailing newline` means that it takes the newline off the end, so you don't end up with it in your string.

Comment: *"so conversion to a string is done to avoid confusion."* - It also helps prevent confusion for users coming from python 2, where `input` returned a parsed input, while `raw_input` returned string input.

Comment: Yes, I seem to remember `raw_input` also left the newline intact?

Comment: *The input from a modern UTF-8 terminal may well be bytes, so conversion to a string is done to avoid confusion.* - I did not understand this point. Please elaborate.

Comment: `sys.stdin` or equivalent that `input` reads from is a `bytes` stream - so it is converted to a string.

Comment: @match Last question: When does the ```input()``` stop reading from ```sys.stdin```?

Comment: `input()` 'watches' for the `newline` (return) character, and stops after that. That's why it has to trim it, as it's already been accepted.

Comment: ```i = input('Enter : '); print(i)``` -  My input: ```niraj\nraut<Enter>``` - Output : ```niraj\nraut``` -Shouldn't the output be ```niraj``` if ```input()``` stops after encountering a newline character?

Comment: '\n' isn't a newline character, it's the characters '\' and 'n' typed one after another.

Answer (score -1):

1. In the Python documentation, arguments inside square brackets are optional
2. `sys.stdin` is a byte stream so decoding is needed to convert bytes to `str`.
3. When "ENTER" is clicked, a newline character is sent to `sys.stdin`. `input` use the newline character to delimit the end of your input. Trailling the newlien is design decision and usually useful. For example, `print(input("Enter your name"))` would not cause two newlines.

Answer (score -1):

Why is there a [] in input([prompt])? Does it signify anything?

You can ignore the bracket. you can use input() like this.

`a = input("Type your age here")`

Second Question: There is no need to convert anymore. The content typed by the user will be a string.